Python Polars rolling() start from window size
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from functime.feature_extractors import FeatureExtractor, binned_entropy

Data_Test = pl.read_csv('./DataDemo.csv')

Calc_T = 200
Data_Test.with_columns(
    pl.col('datetime').cum_count().cast(pl.Int32).alias('Index')
).rolling('Index', period = '{}i'.format(Calc_T)).agg(
    pl.col('datetime').last(),
    pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.binned_entropy(bin_count=10).name.suffix('_binned_entropy'),
    pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.absolute_energy().name.suffix('_absolute_energy'),
    # pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.autocorrelation(n_lags = 20).name.suffix('_autocorrelation')
    
)

In the above code, the line that is commented out will result in an error:PanicException: Cannot apply operation on arrays of different lengths
In polars, DF.rolling('Index', period = '20i'). the first group will be the first row, and the second group will be the first two rows. So the length of the window is less than the length we specified.
I think the reason for the error is that the algorithm in the commented line requires a time series of length greater than 1, and in practice the first group has only one piece of data.
I've tried usegroup_by_dynamic('Index', every = '1i', period = '{}i'.format(Calc_T), start_by = 'datapoint'),But in this case, the length of the last group becomes 1..
Is there a way for Polars to skip the first n-1 rows of data when scrolling through the window, where N is the window length we specified?
Thanks in advance!

Is there a reason you cannot use the offset parameter in the groupby function itself ?
*also on a second note groupby_rolling has been depreciated, you should probably swap to DataFrame.rolling if your on the latest version of polars

Thank you very much for your answer @Karan Shishoo .
First I tried the offset parameter you mentioned, which defaults to-period
If I change the value to '-1i', then the length of the first group is indeed the length we specified, but the resulting problem is that the length of the last group is again 1, which is where I don't quite understand this parameter.
In addition to the polars version you mentioned, I use an older version, which has not been updated .

It is hard to answer definitely without a runnable example. Still, one option might be to perform the operations lazily and take the tail of the (lazy) DataFrame in the last step.
Polars might optimise the query plan, such that the computation is not even performed on the first window (of size 1).
[...]

Calc_T = 200
h = Data_test.height

(
    Data_Test
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('datetime').cum_count().cast(pl.Int32).alias('Index')
    )
    .lazy()
    .rolling('Index', period = '{}i'.format(Calc_T))
    .agg(
        pl.col('datetime').last(),
        pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.binned_entropy(bin_count=10).name.suffix('_binned_entropy'),
        pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.absolute_energy().name.suffix('_absolute_energy'),
        pl.exclude('datetime', 'order_book_id', 'underlying_symbol', 'Index').ts.autocorrelation(n_lags = 20).name.suffix('_autocorrelation')
    )
    .tail(-h+1)
    .collect()
)


Thank you so much! This does allow Polars to perform the corresponding calculation only in the specified tail() and return the correct result, thanks again!!!
